# Why did Harry and Ron destroy the locket Horcrux like this?

Tags: harry-potter

In the film Harry, Ron, and Hermione try to destroy the locket (Horcrux) with their magic wand/spells and it didn't work, that's clear, BUT when Harry found the sword of Gryffindor, Harry and Ron opened the locket to destroy the Horcrux.

To my question:

Why did they have to open the locket to destroy the Horcrux? Couldn't they have just hit the locket with the sword? That would be much easier, right?